# SDM SpatialPoints and raster mask doesn't line up

Tags: r, gis, raster, mask, qgis

I am working on a species distribution model in R and I am trying to iron out some issues in the code early on in the process. I create a mask using climate data rasters from WorldClim. Then I create spatial points from the species observation data. When I then try to plot the spatial points onto my mask it doesn't line up:

[not lining up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqcVc.png)

When I use QGIS just to see if my spatial points line up with a raster layer it lines up as expected:
[lining up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpc8g.png)

Later on in my code I need to create pseudoabsences which doesn't work because it extracts nothing from the mask because there is no mask, it doesn't line up.

I have tried to check if the mask and the data is in the same CRS which it is, I have tried to double check it in QGIS and everything seems to work fine and line up. I have also ensured that the latitude and longitude is not accidentally switched around.

Am I missing something?

Below is the section of code that is giving the issue. I am using R version 4.3.2 and coding in VS Code if that helps.

```
library(raster)

# Read in occurence data
obs_data <- read.csv("data.csv")

# Read the raster files
raster_bio1 <- raster("wc2.1_30s_bio_1.tif")
raster_bio4 <- raster("wc2.1_30s_bio_4.tif")

# create stack of climatic data
clim_SA <- stack(raster_bio1, raster_bio4)
names(clim_SA) <- c("AnnMeanTemp", "TempSeasonality")

#  create mask which is kind of like a base map
#select any variable at the SA scale
mask_SA <- clim_SA$AnnMeanTemp > -500 

# create spatial points of species observation data
pt <- SpatialPoints(obs_data[, c("decimalLongitude", "decimalLatitude")], proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
plot(mask_SA)
plot(pt, pch = 16, col = "red", add = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine. Perhaps the plotting itself goes awry. What does this look like?

```
library(terra)
obs_data <- read.csv("data.csv")
r <- rast("wc2.1_30s_bio_1.tif")
plot(r)
points(obs_data[, c("decimalLongitude", "decimalLatitude")], pch=20, col="red")
```

Comment: It is still giving the same offset points - https://imgur.com/TAbvGyC

Comment: That image cannot be what you get when you do the above

Comment: Apologies, I missed the last part of your code that removed the " proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")" This plots correctly on the map now. But does this translate to spatial points as well?